# I clicked on a delete button within a spam message

Tags: gmail

I clicked on a delete button within a spam message. I realized that the message does not appear within trash messages though it no can be seen in my gmail account. I unistalled the browser and changed my password. What else should I do?

Comment: try to search for the message and report it as spam. Uninstallation of the browser wasn't really necessary.

Comment: The reason I uninstalled the browser was because the button I clicked on was apart of the email message that was designed to trick users, the button was not apart the gmail client. I was thinking whatever it did would probably be executed in the browser. That is why the email did not appear within the trash. So in response to wkim, the message cannot be found in the trash.